# XSLT: Copying certain elements as children of another element

Tags: xml, xslt, copy, element, transformation

I know this transformation is quite trivial; but unfortunately I'm stuck. 
My input is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tests>
    <test>Biography</test>
    <test>Job</test>
    <test>Salary</test>
    <test>FirtsName</test>
    <test>John</test>
    <test>Mary</test>
    <test>David</test>
    <test>Isabella</test>
    <test>SecondName</test>
    <test>Jones</test>
    <test>Williams</test>
    <test>Biography</test>
    <test>Job</test>
    <test>Salary</test>
    <test>FirtsName</test>
    <test>Paul</test>
    <test>Peter</test>
    <test>SecondName</test>
    <test>Castro</test>
    <test>Ricci</test>
<tests>
```

What I want to do, using xslt 2.0, is to choose all elements between the element ""test" with the value "FirstName" and the element "test" with the value "SecondName" and copy them as children of their first preceding "test" element with the value "Biography".
The **OUTPUT** should look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tests>
    <test>Biography
        <test>John</test>
        <test>Mary</test>
        <test>David</test>
        <test>Isabella</test>
    </test>
    <test>Job</test>
    <test>Salary</test>
    <test>FirtsName</test>
    <test>SecondName</test>
    <test>Jones</test>
    <test>Williams</test>
    <test>Biography
        <test>Paul</test>
        <test>Peter</test>
    </test>
    <test>Job</test>
    <test>Salary</test>
    <test>FirtsName</test>
    <test>SecondName</test>
    <test>Castro</test>
    <test>Ricci</test>
</tests>
```

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck with this? -- P.S. Your input is not XML - and neither is your output. You need a single root element.

Comment: I'm basically stuck in the xpath I need. To paraphrase it, I need to find test elements between the first <test>FirtsName</test> and the first <test>SecondName</test> and move them to their nearest preceding <test>Biography<\test> element; then, test elements between the second <test>FirtsName</test> and the second <test>SecondName</test> and move them to their nearest preceding <test>Biography<\test> element, etc. It should be a combination of position and xpath I suppose.

Comment: You need to group first, with group starting with `Biography`. Then within each group you need to identify and move the sub-group between `FirtsName` and `SecondName`. For this, you need to use the XPath `<<` and `>>` operators.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The solution is really straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/tests">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="test" group-starting-with="test[.='Biography']">
            <xsl:variable name="names" select="current-group()[. >> current-group()[.='FirtsName'] and . &lt;&lt; current-group()[.='SecondName']]" />
            <test>
               <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]"/> 
               <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
               <xsl:copy-of select="$names"/>
            </test>
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[position() gt 1] except $names" />
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTAk